# Cannot open libmpc.so.3 while making gcc4.8.1

Tags: c++, gcc

I want to install gcc4.8.1 on ubuntu 10.04.

Here are my installing steps:

1. Install libgmp, libmpfr and libmpc.
2. After switch to gcc4.8.1 source code dir, run "./configure --prefix=/usr/bin/gcc4.8.1 --with-gmp=/opt/pkg/gmp5.1.2 --with-mpfr=/opt/pkg/mpfr3.1.2 --with-mpc=/opt/pkg/mpc1.0.1"
3. make
4. export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/pkg/gmp5.1.2/lib:/opt/pkg/mpfr3.1.2/lib:/opt/pkg/mpc1.0.1/lib
5. sudo make install.

In the last step I get this error:

```
/usr/local/sbin/gcc-4.8.1/host-i686-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/cc1: error while loading shared   libraries: libmpc.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make[5]: *** [install-exec-hook] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/sbin/gcc-4.8.1/i686-pc-linux-gnu/libjava'
make[4]: *** [install-exec-am] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/sbin/gcc-4.8.1/i686-pc-linux-gnu/libjava'
make[3]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/sbin/gcc-4.8.1/i686-pc-linux-gnu/libjava'
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/sbin/gcc-4.8.1/i686-pc-linux-gnu/libjava'
make[1]: *** [install-target-libjava] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/sbin/gcc-4.8.1'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

I have switched to the libmpc library path and tested libmpc.so.3 with ldd. It has been installed successfully. Why does it say it cannot open shared object libmpc.so.3? How can I fix it?

Comment: What a mess!  You are heading for a world of pain with this config.  How do you hope to maintain system-level shared libraries as well as bespoke ones installed in `/opt`.  I also note that you are building in `/usr/local/sbin` and have set the gcc prefix to `/usr/bin/gcc4.8.1`.  Good luck; you'll need it.

Comment: Thank you. I found it's really not wise to install these packages in /opt.

Comment: @trojanfoe, is there a good source to explain those critical stuff like you suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if the libmpc.so.3 is a successfully created symbolic link to libmpc.so.3.0.0. This error may arise because you have installed this library manually and the sym. link may be missing. You could try this:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/pkg/mpc1.0.1/lib/libmpc.so.3.0.0 /opt/pkg/mpc1.0.1/lib/libmpc.so.3
```

Syntax of `ln` is `ln -s <real path to file> <symbolic link name>`. For more check out the man page of [`ln`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ln1.html).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I cannot fix the problem with "ln" command. I have checked the symbol according to your suggest. The symbol link is created successfully.

Answer (score 6):

According to your suggest, I have installed gcc4.8.1 successfully. Here are my steps:

1. Remove gmp, mpfr and mpc from /opt/pkg.
2. Install gmp, mpfr and mpc with the default configure. These packages will be installed in /usr/local/lib.
3. export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
4. Enter the gcc source dir, run "./configure".
5. make.
6. Add symbol links:

   sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so.10 /usr/lib/libgmp.so.10

   sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libmpfr.so.4 /usr/lib/libmpfr.so.4

   sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libmpc.so.3  /usr/lib/libmpc.so.3
7. sudo make install.

Than you KiaMorot. Thank you trojanfoe.

Comment: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib`

this helps me a lot , tks. 

I just write `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`

Comment: The OP should have accepted their own answer here. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...` also solved my problem, see my answer below.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this a second time because it saved me a second time...

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe any of the answers here address the issue. Your problem is the last two steps

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/pkg/gmp5.1.2/lib:/opt/pkg/mpfr3.1.2/lib:/opt/pkg/mpc1.0.1/lib
sudo make install
```

exporting your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is correct, but then you reset all  environment variables when you change to root user with `sudo` in the last step.

One way to get around this:

```
sudo -s  # become root user
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/pkg/gmp5.1.2/lib:/opt/pkg/mpfr3.1.2/lib:/opt/pkg/mpc1.0.1/lib
make install  # don't use sudo here
```

Answer (score 2):

If anybody stumbles upon this using their own manually-built version of libgmp, libmpfr and libmpc instead of the system-provided ones:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/your-prefix-directory
```

is necessary for `make` itself, i.e. even when `gcc` `./configure` was run with

```
--with-gmp=/opt/your-prefix-directory --with-mpc=/opt/your-prefix-directory --with-mpfr=/opt/your-prefix-directory
```

you need to specify where the linker should go looking for libgmp and friends.